# Marklogic 8 nodejs queryBuilder.orderBy SEARCH-BADORDERBY

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I get this

> SEARCH-BADORDERBY: (err:FOER0000) Indexes are required to support element, element-attribute, json-property, or field sort specifications

everytime i try to use the orderBy. I tried in all possible ways.

```
qb.where(qb.value("hasGeolocation", true)).orderBy("username")
```

or

```
qb.where(qb.value("hasGeolocation", true)).orderBy(qb.property("username"))
```

or

```
qb.where(qb.value("hasGeolocation", true)).orderBy(qb.sort("username"))
```

or

```
qb.where(qb.value("hasGeolocation", true)).orderBy(qb.sort(qb.property("username")))
```

and for the sort i tried with 'ascending' or 'descending' direction. Nothing works. Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong with the MarkLogic Node Api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Victor, it looks to me like you haven't defined a range index on "username". Define a string range index on "username" and I think you'll be set.

Comment: Always nice when it's something simple. If you mark this answer as "Accepted", that will be helpful for others with the same problem.